# ROS Answers Search Bar Broken?

Tags: ros, answers.ros.org

[image: Rosanswers logo]

At the risk of sounding foolish, is the ROS answers search bar broken?  It doesn't seem to operate at all like your traditional search bar, and as such I've found the site to be of very limited use.  For example, if you search for "dsp" it does not return any results, even though I'm sure this word is in a posted question and is also a tag.
i.e. http://answers.ros.org/question/1183/real-time-digital-signal-processing-dsp-library

P.S. I've also tried searching for "ROS" and it has shown no results, but maybe this search term was purposefully removed.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10335/ros-answers-search-bar-broken?/) by [wmcmahan](https://answers.ros.org/users/37/wmcmahan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 70 on 2011-06-20

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I assume there is a minimum search length, searching for other three letter words also did not return anything. Searching e.g. for "rviz" works, as does for "roscpp" or "eigen". If that's the case, then it is indeed restricting the search functionality as three-letter acronyms are not that uncommon.

---

Originally posted by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) with karma: 5904 on 2011-06-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1